# a sworn-sister or sworn-brother

Tags: vocabulary

Can we use the term mentioned in the subject for someone who is not our sibling but we respect and care for that person as our sibling? Does this term sound ok? It is of course a home-made phrase but in some cultures in Asia I've heard, they use it. Once they make this relationship, that person is then considered to be like a family member.

Answer (score 2):

The term "[sworn brother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sworn_brother_(disambiguation))" isn't commonly used in modern English, but it is a [known term](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Sworn+brother). It sounds like the sort of thing you might find in semi-historical sagas, such as Viking myths. In past times, people also performed '[blood brother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_brother)' ceremonies to affirm a similar, sworn brother-like relationship. However, the Wikipedia entries for both the terms note that they could also refer to actual siblings.

In modern English, people are more likely to simply say "he's like a brother to me" if a friendship is as close as a family bond. In informal language, there are also colloquial terms like "brother from another mother", although this is not quite so deep as a sworn oath to be like a brother and really just describes a 'best friend' relationship.